# change style sheet when jQuery Mobile back button is clicked

Tags: jquery, mobile, stylesheet

I have this code:

```
$(document).bind('pagebeforeshow', function(e, data) {
  e.preventDefault();
  jQuery.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer({
    beforeload: function( event, ui ) { 
      if (ui.toPage.indexOf('welcome') != -1) {   
        $("head link#styleSheets").attr("href", styles_2.css'); 
      } else {   
        $("head link#styleSheets").attr("href", 'styles.css'); 
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Notice that the style sheet is changed before the page is rendered. It works just fine. Except that it does not work with the back button.

I have tried to fix this. Nothing works so far.

Comment: We need the html and css as well

Comment: Syntax error found. How come it "*works just fine*"

Comment: $("head link#styleSheets").attr("href", 'styles_2.css'); <---- I forgot a ' right before styles_2.css